# Can I leave out 'to' in 'awarded (to) the winners'?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

In the following sentence, can I leave out 'to' before 'the winners'?

> Prizes were awarded (to) the winners by the headmaster.

Comment: Nope you can't exclude 'to' in that sentence, coz no one will know where 'the award' is heading.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatically correct without the **to**. The explanation is long and complicated. You can find all the details here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284389/indirect-object-direct-object-in-active-voice-in-passive-voice

Answer (score 1):

No. If you leave out 'to' it sounds as though you are trying to imply that there are more prizes in addition to the winners - something like this:

> Prizes were awarded; the winners' by the headmaster, the loosers' by
>   the janitor.

So if you want to indicate that the headmaster give the prizes to the winner, then you need the 'to' in your original sentence.

Comment: How about this: Prizes were given us by the headmaster?

Comment: @theinlwin Nope. See the link to the ELU answer in my comment below the OP's question.

Comment: In the 'Practical English Usage by Michael Swan', 'it is said that to' can be omitted before indirect object pronouns. The example sentence: My watch was given (to) me by my father.

Comment: @theinlwin Hmmm - people will understand you without problem, but it sounds very informal and maybe even somewhat uneducated.

Comment: @Steve lves Hmmm - you can google the usage 'given me' in ngram viewer.

Comment: @theinlwin That’s as maybe, Leaving out  ‘to’ is done in some regional dialects, but that doesn’t make it right.

Answer (score 0):

In formal British English you certainly cannot leave out the preposition. In some dialects one hears:"give it me" when in more formal or less dialectal language one would say "give it to me", but I have never heard "award it me".

Comment: The examples you quote are imperatives, whereas the OP's question is about passive voice. There is no connection.

Comment: @JavaLatte It doesn't matter what mood the verb's in: the frame is the same either way.

Comment: @Wilson: You can say "award the prize to me" and you can say "award me the prize".  I am the recipient in these sentences: the winners are the recipients in the OP's sentence. The difference is that the OP's sentence is passive voice.

Comment: @JavaLatte: I don't see that *active/passive* necessarily makes any difference. In my "dialectal" register, *Give it me* is perfectly natural, but so is *It was given me [by the headmaster].*